# how to add vertical mCustomScrollbar to twitter bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a simply vertical scrollbar (mCustomScrollbar) to Bootstrap 3 modal and the  mCustomScrollbar is not showing up. I've added the js and css file from mCustomScrollbar page and in my js file I added `$(".modal-body").mCustomScrollbar(); });` but nothing. Here is what my  css looks like `.modal-body {position: relative;padding: 20px;max-height: 200px; }`. not sure what I am doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to specify overflow (auto or hidden)

```
.modal-body {position: relative;padding: 20px;max-height: 200px; overflow:auto;}
```

Call in a jquery onload function, make sure you call the scrollbar function after the content has loaded (if not then call the update function) and if the content isn't big enough to warrant the scrollbar then it won't show up.

Comment: Thanks b1tsh1ft for the response... still not working

Comment: @jsavage980 sometimes i have noticed that you need to make sure each parent element has a 'height' setting all the way up to the body element, maybe give that a shot?

Comment: thanks again I will do that and let you know if that worked. Appreciate the response.